# Is my approach eligible for a Thread Pool approach?

Tags: c++

I have win 32 C++ application . I have to load 330,000 objects into memory . If I use sequential approach it takes around 16 min . In the threading approach I divide the 330,000 objects equally among 10 containers . I create 10 threads and I assign each thread one container of size  33000 objects to load them in memory  .  This approach took around 9 min .

INcreasing the number of threads did not help .....

Will I get any further improvement if I use ThreadPool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always without specifics, it depends.

Are you loading objects from disk or creating them in memory?  If you're loading them from disk then it's probably IO bound so increasing the number of threads probably won't help very much.

In the comment you mentioned you are loading from a database.  I presume when you use threads you are making N queries simultaneously?  Might be worth investigating the database console to understand how its coping with many concurrent queries.

On the other hand, if the objects are created as the result of some CPU bound process (e.g. calculating pi) then chances are increasing the number of threads grater than the number of CPU's probably won't increase performance (and as ronag points out in the comments will probably hurt performance due to the increased [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)).

Are there dependencies between the objects?  That would again affect how things go.

You'd typically use a thread pool if you have a collection of independent tasks that you want to run with a configurable way of running them.  It sounds like using a thread pool would be a good way to run lots of benchmarks with various thread settings.  You could also make the number of threads configurable which would help when running on different architectures/systems.

Comment: Yes I am loading the objects from database

Comment: I'd just like to add that creating more threads than cpus will not only not increase performance, it will probably even decrease performance.

Comment: Yes the queries are simultaneously passed to the database.   The queries are fined tuned . So have I reached the optimum performance ?

Comment: @Sameer, there's probably more you can do if it's really important.  For example, you might be storing the objects in an STL container.  Have you allocated the size up front (given that you know how many items there are).  The only way you can tell is to profile the application.

Comment: I have already reserved the size of the container up front . Yes I will try profiling .

Answer (score 0):

IME, and yours, a few threads will speed up this kind of task.  I'm guessing that the overall throughput is improved because of better use of the 'intelligent' disk cacheing available on modern controllers - the disk/controller spends less time idle because there are always threads wanting to read something.  The diminishing returns sets in, however, after only a few threads are loaded in and you are disk-bound.  In a slightly similar app, I found that any more than 6 threads provided no additional advantage & just used up more memory.

I can't see how pooling, or otherwise, of these threads would make any difference to performance - it's just a big job that has to be done :(

Tell your customers that they have to install an SSD

Rgds,
Martin